# rank in php based on average values

Tags: php, arrays, rank

I've been trying for a while but still, I'm stuck here. Actually I need to get rank from average values.  Here my result

```
Average         Rank
   39        39 rank is 1
   32        32 rank is 1
   51        51 rank is 1
   57        57 rank is 1
```

what I really need is

```
Average           Rank
  39               3 
  32               4 
  51               2 
  57               1
```

I've tried several method, but nothing seem to be works. Btw Here's my code

```html
<?php $avg = ($sumc)/($data['total']); echo number_format((float)$avg, 2, ',', ''); ?> 

<?php 
$array = array($avg);
$i=1;
foreach($array as $key=>$value) 
{
    $max = max($array);
    echo "\n".$max." rank is ". $i."\n";
    $keys = array_search($max, $array);    
    unset($array[$keys]);
    if(sizeof($array) >0)
    if(!in_array($max,$array))
        $i++;
}
```

And Here's the full Code

```html
<?php $nama_mapel=$ux['nama_mapel'];
$an = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT*FROM mapel where kode_kelas='$kode_kelas' and nama_mapel='$nama_mapel'"))?>
           
<text style="display:none;"><?php if($NILAI_AKHIR!=0){$NILAI_AKHIR4=substr($NILAI_AKHIR/100*4,0,4); echo $NILAI_AKHIR4;} ?></text>
                     <tr>
                    <td width="5%" class="ki1234" height="auto" valign="center" align="center"><?php echo $no++ ;?></td>                     
                    <td width="40%" class="ki1234" height="auto" valign="center" align="left">&nbsp;<?php echo $mmm['nama'];?></td>
     <td width="10%" class="ki1234" height="auto" valign="center" align="center"><?php echo $nis; ?></td>
     <?php 
   
   $mapelz=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM mapel where kode_kelas='$kode_kelas'  and id_tp='$id_tp'");
   $arrg=[];
   while($uxe = mysql_fetch_array($mapelz)){
      $id_mapel=$uxe['id_mapel'];
  
//awal nilai akhir//  
$dren = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM nilai_siswa,data_siswa,penilaian_judul where nilai_siswa.id_penilaian_judul=penilaian_judul.id_penilaian_judul and nilai_siswa.nis=data_siswa.nis and nilai_siswa.nis=$nis and penilaian_judul.id_mapel=$id_mapel and penilaian_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and penilaian_judul.id_tp='$id_tp' order by data_siswa.id_siswa asc"); $jm=mysql_num_rows($dren); $jumlah_tugas=$jm;
if($jm==0){$jumlah="1";} else {$jumlah=$jm; };
$queryj=mysql_query("SELECT sum(n3_100) as rn3_100 FROM nilai_siswa,penilaian_judul where nilai_siswa.id_penilaian_judul=penilaian_judul.id_penilaian_judul and nilai_siswa.nis=$nis and penilaian_judul.id_mapel=$id_mapel and penilaian_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and penilaian_judul.id_tp='$id_tp'");
while($hasil=mysql_fetch_array($queryj))
{$rn3_100=substr($hasil['rn3_100']/$jumlah,0,5); $RATA_TUGAS=$rn3_100;}

$dren = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM nilai_siswa2,data_siswa,penilaian_judul where nilai_siswa2.id_penilaian_judul=penilaian_judul.id_penilaian_judul and nilai_siswa2.nis=data_siswa.nis and nilai_siswa2.nis=$nis and penilaian_judul.id_mapel=$id_mapel and nilai_siswa2.jenis=2 and penilaian_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and penilaian_judul.id_tp='$id_tp' order by data_siswa.id_siswa asc"); $jm=mysql_num_rows($dren); $jumlah_uh=$jm;
if($jm==0){$jumlah="1";} else {$jumlah=$jm;};
$queryj=mysql_query("SELECT sum(n_100) as rn_100 FROM nilai_siswa2,penilaian_judul where nilai_siswa2.id_penilaian_judul=penilaian_judul.id_penilaian_judul and nilai_siswa2.nis=$nis and penilaian_judul.id_mapel=$id_mapel and nilai_siswa2.jenis=2 and penilaian_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and penilaian_judul.id_tp='$id_tp'");
while($hasil=mysql_fetch_array($queryj))
{$rn_100=substr($hasil['rn_100']/$jumlah,0,5); $RATA_UH= $rn_100;}

$dren = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM nilai_siswa2,data_siswa,penilaian_judul where nilai_siswa2.id_penilaian_judul=penilaian_judul.id_penilaian_judul and nilai_siswa2.nis=data_siswa.nis and nilai_siswa2.nis=$nis and penilaian_judul.id_mapel=$id_mapel and nilai_siswa2.jenis=3 and penilaian_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and penilaian_judul.id_tp='$id_tp' order by data_siswa.id_siswa asc"); $jm=mysql_num_rows($dren); $jumlah_uts=$jm;
if($jm==0){$jumlah="1";} else {$jumlah=$jm;};
$queryj=mysql_query("SELECT sum(n_100) as rn_100 FROM nilai_siswa2,penilaian_judul where nilai_siswa2.id_penilaian_judul=penilaian_judul.id_penilaian_judul and nilai_siswa2.nis=$nis and penilaian_judul.id_mapel=$id_mapel and nilai_siswa2.jenis=3 and penilaian_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and penilaian_judul.id_tp='$id_tp'");
while($hasil=mysql_fetch_array($queryj))
{$rn_100=substr($hasil['rn_100']/$jumlah,0,5); $RATA_UTS= $rn_100;}

$dren = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM nilai_siswa2,data_siswa,penilaian_judul where nilai_siswa2.id_penilaian_judul=penilaian_judul.id_penilaian_judul and nilai_siswa2.nis=data_siswa.nis and nilai_siswa2.nis=$nis and penilaian_judul.id_mapel=$id_mapel and nilai_siswa2.jenis=4 and penilaian_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and penilaian_judul.id_tp='$id_tp' order by data_siswa.id_siswa asc"); $jm=mysql_num_rows($dren); $jumlah_us=$jm;
if($jm==0){$jumlah="1";} else {$jumlah=$jm;};
$queryj=mysql_query("SELECT sum(n_100) as rn_100 FROM nilai_siswa2,penilaian_judul where nilai_siswa2.id_penilaian_judul=penilaian_judul.id_penilaian_judul and nilai_siswa2.nis=$nis and penilaian_judul.id_mapel=$id_mapel and nilai_siswa2.jenis=4 and penilaian_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and penilaian_judul.id_tp='$id_tp'");
while($hasil=mysql_fetch_array($queryj))
{$rn_100=substr($hasil['rn_100']/$jumlah,0,5); $RATA_US= $rn_100;}

if(!isset($RATA_TUGAS)){$RATA_TUGAS2=0;}else{$RATA_TUGAS2=$RATA_TUGAS;};
     if(!isset($RATA_UH)){$RATA_UH2=0;}else{$RATA_UH2=$RATA_UH;};
     if(!isset($RATA_UTS)){$RATA_UTS2=0;}else{$RATA_UTS2=$RATA_UTS;};
     if(!isset($RATA_US)){$RATA_US2=0;}else{$RATA_US2=$RATA_US;};
$jumlahc=($persen['tugas']*$RATA_TUGAS2)/100+($persen['uh']*$RATA_UH2)/100+($persen['uts']*$RATA_UTS2)/100+($persen['us']*$RATA_US2)/100;

       if($jumlah_tugas!=0){$k=1;} else {$k=0;};
       if($jumlah_uh!=0){$l=1;} else {$l=0;};
       if($jumlah_uts!=0){$m=1;} else {$m=0;};
       if($jumlah_us!=0){$n=1;} else {$n=0;};
       $JUMLAH_PERSEN1=($persen['tugas']*$k)+($persen['uh']*$l)+($persen['uts']*$m)+($persen['us']*$n);
       if($JUMLAH_PERSEN1==0){$JUMLAH_PERSEN=1;}else{$JUMLAH_PERSEN=$JUMLAH_PERSEN1;};
       $NILAI_AKHIRg=substr(($jumlahc/$JUMLAH_PERSEN)*100,0,5);
$nile= $NILAI_AKHIRg;
$arrg[] = $NILAI_AKHIRg;} ?>
    
        <?php $p = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM peringkat WHERE kode_kelas='$kode_kelas' and nis='$nis'and id_tp='$id_tp'")); ?>  
  <text style="display:none;"> <?php $sumc = 0; $output = ""; while($element = array_shift($arrg)){$sumc += $element; $output .= $element; if(sizeof($arrg) > 0){ $output .= " + ";}} echo $output . PHP_EOL;?></text>
   <td width="15%" class="ki1234" height="auto" valign="center" align="center"><?php echo $sumc;?></td> 
   <text style="display:none;"><?php $result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total FROM mapel WHERE kode_kelas='$kode_kelas' and kel!=3"); $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result); echo $data['total'];?></text>
    <td width="15%" class="ki1234" height="auto" valign="center" align="center"><?php $avg = ($sumc)/($data['total']); echo number_format((float)$avg, 2, ',', ''); ?></td> 
   <td width="15%" class="ki1234" height="auto" valign="center" align="center"><?php 
$array = array($avg);
$i=1;
foreach($array as $key=>$value) 
{
    $max = max($array);
    echo "\n".$max." rank is ". $i."\n";
    $keys = array_search($max, $array);    
    unset($array[$keys]);
    if(sizeof($array) >0)
    if(!in_array($max,$array))
        $i++;
}
?></td> 
         
                  </tr>
      <?php }?>
```

Need Your help.. Anyone..?!

Comment: `$array` only has a single element in the code you posted. Is there other (relevant) code around this?

Comment: Only advice I can give you is: *first* build an array, *then* start outputting a table. You are now trying to determine the rank of a number on its own, that's always going to be 1.

Comment: @Justastudent How to add another element..? btw i just posted my big code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign a rank number to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461205/how-to-assign-a-rank-number-to-an-array)

Comment: Most of your posted code is irrelevant to the question, but it showed enough for me to write my comment about first building an array, then outputting a table. I have linked a question about determining the rank of numbers in an array. Adding a value `$value` to an array `$array` is as simple as `$array[] = $value`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $avg = ($sumc)/($data['total']); echo number_format((float)$avg, 2, ',', ''); ?> 

<?php 
$array = array($avg); // useless
$i=1;
foreach($array as $key=>$value)  // also useless, you never use these variables, and since $array contains only one entry, there is no need to foreach it
{
    $max = max($array);
    echo "\n".$max." rank is ". $i."\n";
    $keys = array_search($max, $array);    
    unset($array[$keys]);
    if(sizeof($array) >0)
    if(!in_array($max,$array))
        $i++;
}
```

Let's clean that up :

```
<?php $avg = ($sumc)/($data['total']); echo number_format((float)$avg, 2, ',', ''); ?> 

<?php 
$max = $avg; // That's actually what you were doing. Cleaning the code makes it obvious, that's all
echo "\n".$max." rank is ". $i."\n";
$keys = array_search($max, $array);    
unset($array[$keys]);
if(sizeof($array) >0)
if(!in_array($max,$array))
    $i++;
}
```

The code still has errors, but the more we correct, the more its design flaws appear, and the less it's therefore correctable.
You should, in my opinion, look at that code, figure a way to put all the values you want to have in $array in it so that **then** you can compute the datas you need.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted seems the problem is how to sort the average values descending.

With this in mind you know that if you're calculating the average on the go, you have to go throuh the entire array first so here's some snippet to help you:

```
// Random values I want to calculate the average
$values = [
    1 => [15, 25, 35],
    2 => [45, 55, 65],
    3 => [75, 85, 95],
    4 => [105, 115, 125]
];

$avgs = array();
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    $avgs[$key] = array_sum($value) / count($value); // calculate average for each key on the array
}

print_r($avgs);
// Will print:
// Array
// (
//    [1] => 25
//    [2] => 55
//    [3] => 85
//    [4] => 115
//)

arsort($avgs); // sort the array in descending order
print_r($avgs);

// Will print:
//Array
//(
//    [4] => 115
//    [3] => 85
//    [2] => 55
//    [1] => 25
//)
```

So there if have your avg array sorted, therefore you have your "rank".

ps. The keys 1, 2, 3, 4 are just random values, you could have anything there.